# image inside svg not scaling on mouse hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a image inside my svg, and i want to scale that image on mouse hover using css.

this is my svg document.

```
 <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1260 720" width="1260px" height="740px" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">
<g>
    <g id="step-5">
   <image overflow="visible" class="step-circle-5" width="173" height="173" 
 xlink:href="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAK0AAACsCAYAAAAJ8yzmAAA
  ACXBIWXMAAAkSAAAJEgFGxru7AAAA.. transform="matrix(0.9334 0 0 0.9389 843.2724 402.5272)"></image>

  <text transform="matrix(1.0004 0 0 1 825.4094 649.0767)" fill="#A9D48D" font-size="92">5</text>
 </g>
....
</g>
</svg>
```

And here is the css

```
.step-circle-5:hover{
    transform: translate(843.2724 402.5272) scale(1.2) translate(843.2724 402.5272);
    -webkit-transform: translate(843.2724 402.5272) scale(1.2) translate(843.2724 402.5272);
}
```

**Here is the complete code on [codepen](https://codepen.io/gudboisgn/pen/JJjEvr)**

Answer (score 1):

I think that your selector is wrong, try this:

```
/*  .step-circle-1 is last <image> tag in svg document */
svg .step-circle-1:hover{
  cursor:pointer;
  transform: scale(1.2)
  translate(5%,50%);
}
```

With the translate you must play a little bit...